# Tesseract 3.03 english language data

Tags: tesseract-ocr

Tesseract 3.03 have been released recently and I have just installed it. Nevertheless, English language data is not provided with the download (from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tesseract/3.03.03-1). On the Tesseract website, there is a "Download" link but you can only find "English language data for Tesseract 3.02". Where could I find those for 3.03?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned by others you can use 3.02's english language packs for 3.03.
Below are the instructions:

1. Download and unzip from here : [1](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B7l10Bj_LprhQnpSRkpGMGV2eE0&usp=sharing#list)
2. Install pre-requisites and unzip

   ```
   `sudo apt-fast install -y libicu-dev libpango1.0-dev libcairo2-dev`
   `tar xfv tesseract-ocr-3.02.eng.tar.gz`
   ```
3. Extract Tesseract's English data pack to tessdata directory inside tesseract-3.03 directory. Assuming both(English language data and tesseract source .tar.gz files) are in the same folder

   `tar zxvf tesseract-ocr-3.02.eng.tar.gz`

mv tesseract-ocr/tessdata/*.* tesseract-3.03/tessdata/

4.Go back to tesseract's directory and finish the installation

```
cd tesseract-3.03

./autogen.sh

./configure

make -j

sudo make install LANGS="eng"

sudo ldconfig
```

Now test your installation with the test image in the directory

```
tesseract phototest.tif  ans -l eng
cat ans.txt
```

Output:

> This is a lot of 12 point text to test the
> ocr code and see if it works on all types
> of file format.
>
> The quick brown dog jumped over the lazy fox. The quick brown dog
> jumped over the lazy fox. The quick brown dog jumped over the lazy
> fox. The quick brown dog jumped over the lazy fox.

NOTE: some lines have wrong formatting...any advice to correct those would be great

Answer (score 1):

You can use the language data from 3.02 on 3.03 RC.

Also please note that 3.03 has not yet been released officially. That is an RC build.